# How does Don Flamingo's fruit production work?

Tags: one-piece

I'm new here and I'm wondering what kind of Devil fruits Don Flamingo produced.

- Are this Fruits as Strong as normal fruits?
- If maybe the fire fruit already exists, can they produce the same fruit another time, so there would be 2 fire fruits?
- Can they manipulate which fruits they produce? or is this a random process?

Comment: Well, SMILE is always a zoan, so it will never be 2 fire fruits :) Otherwise... we don't know yet.

Comment: ah SMILE is just zoan? didn't know that. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is still unknown. We still don't have any precise details on how the factory works.
We just know that the Smile are Zoan-type fruits, and that probably they achived these smiles by studying a prototype artifical fruit made by Vegapunk (i.e. the dragon fruit that Momonosuke ate).

Comment: Well, we do know it is not exactly a factory. But more something like a orchard. And that it uses rivers induced with SAD to produce the devil fruits. SAD was the material vega punk used to create the artificial devil fruits.